# What coordinate system uses three places for decimal minutes for longitude values?

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, degrees-minutes-seconds

I have data from a navigation unit that is reporting coordinates where the latitude is in a familiar decimal minutes format (e.g., 26° 14.12345’) that never has the number of places (I,e., the 14 in example above) exceed two characters. But for the longitude it is reporting values where the places for the decimal minutes have three characters, like 055° 126.12345’).

I am familiar with how the degree portion of longitude can range to three places because it can go 180 E/W, but I’m perplexed at seeing the minutes value have more than two places (because more than 60 minutes would roll you over to the next full degree).  More interestingly it seems, if I remove the value in the hundreds place (“1” in the above example of “126”) then the overall coordinate plots where I would expect, though I can’t necessarily confirm. Sometimes the value in the hundreds place of the decimal minute takes on values as high as 9, like 934.12345’ for example. This is also strange.

Comment: Is there (also) a projected CRS set? I'm wondering if the wrong UTM zone is chosen and the inverse projection is messing up somehow. Or, more likely, they're doing something funky in a DD or DMS conversion to DM format.